# Error Procedure MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've created a procedure into my database of a Veterinary Clinic.

The procedure should add 10 packages for each a drug that a specific animal currently taking (the animal is identificated by the id ('Animal'), that is the input parameter of the procedure), and that are not present in the clinic in a quantity exceeding 5 packages. (In table 'PhysicalDrug' there are the packages of the drug that are present in clinic.)

In other words all drugs in the table 'Prescription' that have been prescribed to the animal where the row 'End_date' is NULL or is in the future and of which there are few packages in clinic.

The procedure that I made only works for the first record that respects the conditions listed above, but skips other, I don't know why, Can you help me? thank you very much!
(Sorry for my bad English >.<)

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE add_Drug(IN animal INTEGER)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE Code VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE i, eof INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cdrugs CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT P.Code_drug 
        FROM   Prescription P
        WHERE  P.Id_animal = animal
          AND (P.End_date IS NULL OR P.End_date >= CURDATE());

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET eof = 1;

    # the function counter returns the greater id of the table PhysicalDrug incremented by one
    SET @Id = counter();
    OPEN cdrugs;
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cdrugs INTO Code;
      IF eof = 1 THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;
      #Memorize the number of units of the drug present in the clinic 
      SET @NumberDrug =
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM PhysicalDrug
          WHERE Code_drug = Code);
      IF @NumberDrug < 5 THEN
        WHILE i < 10 DO
          INSERT INTO PhysicalDrug (Id, Code_drug)
            VALUES (@Id, Code);
          SET i = i + 1;
          SET @Id = @Id + 1;
        END WHILE;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cdrug;
  END //
  DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little reformatting of your code reveals the answer: After you loop through your `INSERT` the first 10 times, you ***never reset the counter `i`***. After that, `i < 10` is always false, so you never enter your `INSERT` loop again.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :D I had not noticed it :O